# Deciding between anova or t-test

Tags: r, anova

I have two categorical variables with 4 different attributes. I want to check if these two categorical variables differ from each other (based on 4 attributes) using ANOVA in `R`. The example data is below:

```
values  dims
-4.75   dim1PK
-5.69   dim1PK
-0.27   dim1PK
-2.76   dim1PK
-8.24   dim1PK
-12.51  dim1PK
-1.28   dim1PK
0.95    dim1US
-5.96   dim1US
-8.81   dim1US
-8.46   dim1US
-6.15   dim1US
-13.98  dim1US
-16.43  dim1US
-4.09   dim1US
-11.06  dim1US
-9.04   dim1US
-8.56   dim1US
-8.13   dim2PK
-14.46  dim2PK
-4.21   dim2PK
-4.96   dim2PK
-5.48   dim2PK
-4.53   dim2PK
6.31    dim2PK
-11.16  dim2PK
-1.27   dim2US
-11.49  dim2US
-0.9    dim2US
-12.27  dim2US
6.85    dim2US
-5.21   dim2US
-1.06   dim2US
-2.6    dim2US
-0.95   dim2US
-0.82   dim3PK
-7.65   dim3PK
0.64    dim3PK
-2.25   dim3PK
-1.58   dim3PK
-5.73   dim3PK
0.37    dim3PK
-5.46   dim3US
-3.48   dim3US
0.88    dim3US
-2.11   dim3US
-10.13  dim3US
-2.08   dim3US
-4.33   dim3US
1.09    dim4PK
-4.23   dim4PK
-1.46   dim4PK
9.37    dim4PK
5.84    dim4PK
8.21    dim4PK
7.34    dim4PK
1.83    dim4US
14.39   dim4US
22.02   dim4US
4.83    dim4US
```

As you can see I have stacked the data to fulfill r `aov` function's requirement. I also understand a bit how ANOVA works (variation within group versus variation between groups). And, that `TukeyHSD` (post-hoc test) is required to see if groups of interest differ from each other significantly.

### And now the question:

1. Should I perform a one-way ANOVA with a post-hoc test? That will give a significant p-value (as the data distributions of dim1, dim2, dim3 and dim4 are different from each other by definition, the group comparisons like PKdim1-PKdim2 will show more between group variation which will in turn affect ANOVA). Then I simply ignore attribute to attribute (PKdim1-PKdim2, PKdim2-USdim3) group comparisons and only look at the desired ones (1: PKdim1-USdim1, 2: PKdim2-USdim2, 3: PKdim3-USdim3, 4: PKdim4-USdim4).
2. Should I perform 4 t-tests one by one and report the results separately?

Please help me get some clarification in this regard.

Comment: Welcome.   please state your hpotheses.

Comment: My hypothesis is that the four groups (dim1PK-dim1US, dim2PK-dim2US, dim3PK-dim3US, dim4PK-dim4US) have significant differences. If not all at least some of them. Step 1 of ANOVA won't tell that (because groups like dim1-PK-dim2PK.... groups within the two variables will also contribute to overall variation). But step 2, the Tukey HSD, will clarify where is the actual variation.